# Blocking one domain with a robots.txt

Tags: blogger, robots.txt

If Blogger is serving a site at both mydomain.com and mydomain.blogspot.com, and the two sites are identical right down to having the same robots.txt file, is there some way to configure the robots.txt file so that it only blocks indexing of the mydomain.blogspot.com version of the site? Is there any other way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with robots.txt, which can only contain instructions for the folders / subfolders, not domains / subdomains. You may want to create separate robots.txt file for mydomain.com and mydomain.example.com, if possible.

Another solution is to make a permanent 301 redirect from one domain to the other. Isn't that possible with Blogger?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to make sure that the mydomain.blogspot.com gets redirected to your custom domain mydomain.com. The redirect will need to be a permanent redirect (301) and it can be achieved with blogs hosted on Blogger.
Here this should help you through:

http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs

and here is another one but with the previous look of Blogger.
http://www.blogbloke.com/redirect-you-blogger-custom-domain-to/

I suggest you use the first link and follow step by step procedure!